# Valgrind ignore templates in output

Tags: c++, valgrind, callgrind, kcachegrind

I'm using `valgrind [callgrind]` to profile a C++ executable, and `KCachegrind` to display the results. However, the function names are all but unreadable due to endless template names before the actual method name. Since each class is instantiated with one fixed template value, this is purely wasteful.
Is there a way to get an output of the kind `MyClass<...>::methodName()`, with literal dots in place of the template?

Comment: you can refactor your code such that `...` is just a short name, though not sure if producing readable valgrind output would justify it

Comment: Indeed. I was hoping for a non-refactoring solution.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but you can try replacing the long stuff with a short name from the output before opening in KCachegrind